# I need to be able to block the typing of certain keywords into google chrome, is there anyway to do this?

Tags: blocking, keyword

Is there anyway to simply block keywords being typed into search engines like google/youtube that block you access whenever that specific keyword is typed in?

Comment: Why do you need to block specific words?  Are you trying to block access to certain websites?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Without going into too much information I want to be able to block access to certain youtube videos/sites popping up without having to use google chrome extensions as they can be disabled quite easily.

Comment: I have chrome extensions that do the job but I can kill them easily..if there was a way to disable access through the chrome task manager or to restart extensions as soon as they were killed that'd be great too.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without an extension.

Comment: Any idea how to stop extensions being disabled so easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about how the search bar autosearches for matches based on what you're typing, I wouldn't have the faintest clue other than to shut that feature off, completely.

For blocking custom domains, however, I used [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org) for years for accomplishing similar tasks, such as blocking certain advertising sites.  Also, your question made me wonder about wildcards in the hosts file, which led me to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138162/wildcards-in-a-windows-hosts-file).  Perhaps one of those will help you.